# Visual Studio 2008 Explicit Reference Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, intellisense, reference

I have a project which references a dll in the same solution (called "Common"). Common has two types of errors with the same names but different namespaces i.e.

Common.Login.UserDeleted
Common.Imaging.UserDeleted

When I type UserDeleted visual studio recognizes both of these and asks for which it is ("ambiguous reference"). I right-click UserDeleted and select one of the two above, yet it then says that the type or reference doesn't exist! It doesn't make any sense. Why is this happening? I can't compile my program until I find a solution to this, thanks

Comment: Do you know which of the two types you want to use? Or did you just pick one at random?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bother, the problem was that in my Common dll there was one type that had the same namespace as my client dll (i.e. Client.Common instead of Common). I don't know why it confused Visual Studio but it compiles now. Thanks again for offering your assistance